# Binding a button tooltip for every row in the datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have a datagrid that has buttons in the first column which expand another datagrid under each row. I want the tooltip to show the number of rows that are inside the datagrid. Right now I'm trying to just get the tooltip however to display some text through binding it with a property however nothing is showing. Here's my xaml for the button inside the datagrid:

```
<Control:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <Control:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Click="ShowHideDetailsClick" Foreground="Black" 
                         ToolTip="{Binding ToolTipDetails}">+</Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Control:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</Control:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

C#:

```
public string ToolTipDetails
{
        get { return _toolTip; }
        set
        {
            if (_toolTip != value)
            {
                _toolTip = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ToolTipDetails");
            }
        }
}

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

and in my Load Window event, I'm setting this:

```
ToolTipDetails = "ChildTrades: 0";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the grid ItemSource property. Here

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Data">
               <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Foreground="Black" ToolTip="{Binding ToolTipDetails}" Click="ShowHideDetailsClick" FontSize="16">+</Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Then in the code behind i did

```
List<Data> items = new List<Data> { new Data() { ToolTipDetails = "Tip one here" }, new Data() { ToolTipDetails = "Tip two here" } };
DataGrid.ItemsSource = items;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you data bind to a `DataGrid`, in one way or another, you set the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` to a collection of some kind, or perhaps a `DataTable` even. The point is that it is a collection of items and the properties or columns of these items are data bound to the various columns in the `DataGrid`.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}" />
```

Each item in the collection is represented by one row in the `DataGrid`. If you want to data bind different data to a `ToolTip` property *in every row of the `DataGrid`*, then you need to provide a property or column for each item of the `YourCollection` collection to data bind to. In this way, you could do what you want *where the data item in `DataGrid` row* has a property or column named `ToolTipDetails`:

```
<Control:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Button Click="ShowHideDetailsClick" Foreground="Black" 
         ToolTip="{Binding ToolTipDetails}">+</Button>
    </DataTemplate>
</Control:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```